# Add background image in SVG

Tags: css, svg, background-image

I need to add background image in svg. But I'm getting only black rectangle box, the image is not displaying. How to add the background image?

This is my code:

```
<style>
    path {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 3px;
        stroke-linejoin: round;
        stroke-linecap: round;
    }
</style>

<svg width="1000" height="700">
    <!-- <rect fill="#fff" width="100%" height="100%"></rect> -->

    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="700">
            <image xlink:href="home/nayana/Documents/Text Editor Files/abstract-hd.jpg" width="600" height="450" />             
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <path d="M5,5 l0,680 l980,0 l0,-680 l-980,0 fill="url(#img1)" />
</svg>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: that folder name is given with space, so i gave with space in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct a syntax error in the path, you are missing a `"` at the end and remove `fill:none` from CSS that is overriding the fill attribute used with the path:

[image]

Full code:

```css
path {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

```html
<svg width="1000" height="700">
    <!-- <rect fill="#fff" width="100%" height="100%"></rect> -->

    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="700">
                    <image xlink:href="https://lorempixel.com/600/450/" width="600" height="450" />             
            </pattern>
    </defs>
    <path d="M5,5
        l0,680 l980,0 l0,-680 l-980,0"          
        fill="url(#img1)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Now i corrected my syntax. its working now. Thank you  @Temani Afif

Answer (score 2):

Simplest use nowadays is plain `<image href="bgnd.png"/>`. This also can take x, y, width, height. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image